# Django 1.8: Can't use querysets in query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-1.8

I'm trying to do this:

```
wider_circle = # some queryset
friends_you_may_know = list(wider_circle.exclude(user_id__in=user.connections))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
RemovedInDjango19Warning: Passing callable arguments to queryset is deprecated
```

It worked on Django 1.6 but throws an error on 1.8

Thanks :)

Comment: This appears to be a deprecation warning and not an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that `connections` is a Many to Many on the user model. Which means that `user.connections` is an instance of the related manager. You should try passing a `queryset` instance ie:

```
friends_you_may_know = list(wider_circle.exclude(user_id__in=user.connections.all()))
```